# OnCheckedChanged not being fired on re-population of the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, oncheckedchanged

I have a Gridview that has two buttons Edit & Delete.

On Edit, the row command calls a function called "Populate()" that populates a form located above the grid in a Panel (sets visible = true ).

**Problem:**

I have a checkbox "cbX", a textbox "txtX", and a dropdownlist "ddlX"(Visible = false)

if cbX is selected => ddlX.Visible = true and txtX.Enabled = false (I have an onCheckChangeed function)

When i chose to edit the entry, in the grid, that originally has cbX.Checked = true  I face a problem when the user attempts to uncheck the checkbox. No error is returned it simply does not call the onCheckChanged when I need it to hide the ddlX and Enable the txtX

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtX" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbX" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Unable to Obtain " OnCheckedChanged="cbX_CheckedChanged" />

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlX" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Code" AppendDataBoundItems="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlX_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="350px" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" Enabled="false" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Bind your `DataBind` in `if (!isPostBack)` in `Page_Load`

Comment: care to elaborate how does that effect it. Also the "if ( ! IsPostBack) " contains a function the fills the grid. what exactly should I bind there? Note: On page load the 3 fields I specified are hidden until the user chooses to edit a field from the grid. @Asif.Ali

Comment: the only issue is when I deselect the checkbox (for the first time) after i select to edit the field the checkchanged event is not being fired but then works fine after checking and unchecking.

Comment: This is because `CheckBox` is not a gridview control. You have to attach `OnCheckChanged` event in gridView `RowBinding` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
I needed to manually add this:

```
cbX.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.cbX_CheckedChanged);
```

in the function that repopulates the form.